# Any way to disable the quick settings panel on the lockscreen on Android 12 and 11?

Tags: lock-screens, android-11, android-12, quick-settings

Is there any way to disable the quick settings panel on the lockscreen on Android 12 and 11?
I want to disable it, just like it used to be on the older Android versions.

If I cannot the disable it, can it be abused if my phone is lost or stolen?

Comment: What phone model are you using?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy A52s 5G, but I might need this for some other phones I might buy in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded an app called [Cerberus Lockscreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lsdroid.lsp) and it did the job. Blocks both the shutdown and pull-down menu.

For older Android versions there is [Lockscreen protector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alpinesoftit.lockscreenprotector) app, but it does not block pull-down menu but only shutdown menu.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the device(s). You can't do it on Pixel 6 for example as the setting to disable quick settings panel is not present in Android 12.

For Samsung devices, you can disable  as indicated [here](https://mobileinternist.com/disable-quick-settings-menu-lock-screen):

> On Samsung devices, there’s a separate Lock screen menu so you can find the option in Settings > Lock screen > Secure lock settings. Once you enter your screen lock PIN/password/pattern, look for the Lock network and security setting. By enabling it, you’ll lock Quick Settings access from the lock screen.

For  Xiaomi, Redmi and POCO devices, you can disable it by following the steps shown [here](https://igamesnews.com/mobile/how-to-lock-quick-settings-from-lock-screen-on-xiaomi/):

> - Go to settings”.
> - Go to “Notifications and control center”.
> - Tap “Items show on lock screen after swiping down”.
> - Disable “Control Center”.

Comment: I still have access to the quick settings.

Comment: It doesn't work for Poco. I cant disable control centre https://i.stack.imgur.com/QstI9.jpg